# Extra storage space for HP Proliant DL380 G5

Tags: hp, scsi

I have a HP Proliant DL380 G5, SAS Hard-disk no space left, I am planning to buy HP StorageWorks MSA20 Sata -  thus, a total of 6TB area will be formed.

I do not know how to do connection server with storagework.

I guess I need to buy them;

1. One 3' VHDCI SCSI cable
2. Ultra320 SCSI I/O host connectivity (I'm not
       sure this card)
3. 6 x 1TB WD HDD or 12 x 500 GB WD HDD

or how do I create extra space for the server?

If you write simple English, I'll be very happy with your answer

[HP 20 Modular Smart Array pdf](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04283164.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

To use the MSA20, you will need an Ultra320 SCSI card installed in your server.  This is the  `Smart Array 6404, Smart Array 6402, Smart Array 642 [or] the Smart Array 6i Controllers` mentioned several times in the Quickspecs.  If you have such a thing already, great! If not, you should be able to pick one of these up pretty cheap (quick googling shows a price range of approx $20-$100 for a 6402).

Be aware though you probably will also need a riser card to install it in your server - this is simply an adapter that allows you to mount the card horizontally instead of vertically.

According to the Quickspecs, and assuming you are purchasing the MSA20 new, a 3 foot VHDCI cable should be included.

Pick the drives according to your needs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I need a Smart Array 6404 or others but No place for this card on the motherboard.. card entry with slots inputs different [Image 1](https://velocityanne.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/fig-6.jpg) - 
[Image 2](https://velocityanne.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/fig-5.jpg)

Comment: Do you have an extra need for this piece?

Comment: The controller card will plug into the piece shown in Image1 - that's the riser that allows you mount cards horizontally.  All it basically does is rotate the slots 90 degrees.

Comment: I created an image, this is my biggest question mark [Image 3](http://oi61.tinypic.com/14visnb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

***You're looking at the wrong product for this server...***

If you want disk expansion for an old G5 ProLiant, you'll want to use the period-correct MSA60 (12-3.5" drive bays) or MSA70 (25-2.5" drive bays).

The [MSA20](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04283164.pdf) was intended for earlier server models and appeared around the introduction of SATA disks (2004). It is only capable of 1.5Gbps SATA and requires a SCSI connection to the host server. In order to use the SCSI connection and a supported Smart Array controller (641, 6402, 6404), you'd have to obtain the optional mixed riser cage (Part #410570-B21)... But this is all obsolete technology.

You'd be much better off with an [MSA60 storage unit](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04140658.pdf?ver=37) and any compatible SAS controller: Smart Array P800/P411/P212.